# Ubuntu 22.04.1 AMD GPU Driver isn't loaded although it is installed

Tags: 22.04, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I have installed AMD GPU Driver using `amdgpu-install_22.20.50200-1_all.deb`(downloaded from amd.com) and following [this guide](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/1122).

But I found that my display setting changed to `2560x1440 93Hz` and I couldn't change it.

I tried `sudo lshw -c video` and it said `UNCLAIMED`.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:4000000000-400fffffff memory:4010000000-40101fffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:80000000-8007ffff memory:80080000-8009ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 3
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=2560,1440
```

I checked my kernel version too.

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-50-generic
$ dkms status amdgpu
amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.1 and Windows 11.

i9 10900K, RX 5700XT

Fast Startup, Secure Boot, TPM 2.0 enabled.

I modified bcd bootmgr path as grub.

```
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor                                 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.1 AMD-APP (3452.0)
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback 
  Platform Extensions function suffix             AMD
  Platform Host timer resolution                  1ns

  Platform Name                                   AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  No platform
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No platform
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [other]              
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 2560 x 1440, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 2560 x 1440
default connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   2560x1440     93.00*
```

I already added `radeon` into `/etc/modules`.
I already configured `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` like below.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev c1)
```

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier             "Screen0"
    Driver                 "amdgpu"
    VendorName             "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    BusID                  "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier             "Screen1"
    Driver                 "amdgpu"
    VendorName             "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    BusID                  "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection
```

But `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` says `No screen section available. Using defaults`.

```
[    15.172] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    15.172] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    15.172] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    15.172] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    15.172] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using the first device section listed.
[    15.172] (**) |   |-->Device "Screen0"
[    15.172] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Screen1"
[    15.172] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.

...

[    15.180] (II) AMDGPU: Driver for AMD Radeon:
        All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver
[    15.180] (II) AMDGPU(0): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    15.180] (EE) AMDGPU(0): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:03:00.0: No such file or directory
[    15.180] (II) AMDGPU(1): [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    15.180] (EE) AMDGPU(1): [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:03:00.0: No such file or directory
[    15.181] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    15.181] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    15.181] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    15.181] (II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
[    15.181] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[    15.181] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[    15.181] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    15.181] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    15.181] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3

...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would remove `radeon` from `/etc/modules`, and get rid of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` as well. Also, use an AMD GPU Driver provided by AMD, and not "my AMD GPU Driver" or "my friend's AMD GPU Driver", etc, whatever that even means.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I'm not english native. I disalbed fastboot on BIOS and re-installed ubuntu 22.04.1, downloaded driver from amd.com, and installed it. Now it works! I don't know which solved this problem (disabling fastboot? not adding ppa repository?)